# Background slideshow (javascript) fade effect

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow, fade

I am trying to apply the fade effect to the javascsript background slideshow. When I changed the value, JS ignored it. I tried `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`. What is wrong with this code?

```
var bgimages=new Array()
bgimages[0]="tenis.jpg"
bgimages[1]="rtrr.jpg"
bgimages[2]="tenis.jpg"

//preload images
var pathToImg=new Array()
for (i=0;i<bgimages.length;i++) {
    pathToImg[i]=new Image()
    pathToImg[i].src=bgimages[i]
}
var inc=-1

function bgSlide() {
    if (inc<bgimages.length-1)
        inc++
    else
        inc=0

    document.body.background=pathToImg[inc].src
}

if (document.all||document.getElementById)
    window.onload=new Function('bgSlide(); setInterval("bgSlide()",3000),fade(2000)')
```

Comment: Where is your face-function?

Comment: window.onload=new Function('bgSlide(); setInterval("bgSlide()",3000),fade(2000)')

Comment: Thats where you call the function, but where is it defined?

Comment: i do not understand. Here is example http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp . It is not defined.

Comment: Ok, so have you included jQuery in your html-file? The example you linked to uses jQuery, that is a library that you need to include?

I'm not sure, but i don't think you can do fadeIn/Out effects on background images with jQuery. Try putting your images inside a <img>-tag